# Updating Task Definitions in ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I'm currently trying to automate my build and deployment process through CodePipeline. After my code finishes building in codebuild, I want to update my task definition and update my service through the aws cli via CodeBuild.

I'm having a problem with updating the service because there's no way for me to keep track of the revision number. Is there a way to let the updated service know to use the latest revision? I know that you can specify a json, but how can I manipulate the revision number so that the service points to the right image in my registry?

Comment: You can leave the revision number (and colon) off of the task definition to force your service to use the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a little the documentation of the api of Amazon, does not tell you which is the last image that was uploaded. I recommend that in the process of upload captures the version to be able to set it in the service.

I leave you the response of the api when you list the images.

Response syntax:

```
{
   "imageIds": [ 
      { 
         "imageDigest": "string",
         "imageTag": "string"
      }
   ],
   "nextToken": "string"
}
```

A possible process can be:

- Obtain the tag of your repo:

`TAG=$(git describe --always)`

- Build the image with this tag:

`docker build . -t [acount].dkr.ecr.[zone].amazonaws.com/[app]:TAG`

- Push the image:

`docker push [acount].dkr.ecr.[zone].amazonaws.com/[app]:TAG`

- Update the task with the image:
- Update the service with the task

Hope this can help you

Comment: thank you so much for the help, i ended up using CodeBuild with the revision number provided in the global environment variable which makes it very easy to keep track of each image!

Comment: you can use this command 
aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition web-server | egrep "revision" | tr "/" " " | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"$//'